# How can I display a specific PDF from an S3 bucket on a unique URL based on object name?

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, next.js

I currently have multiple pdfs held on S3 and I'm building an app where I need to display these PDFs based on the name of the object. For example, I have a pdf named photosynthesis 1.pdf, it's held in the biology/ folder and I need to display this pdf on domain.com/exams/{biology}/{photosynthesis 1.pdf}

How can I make it so that when a user visits this url, it displays the pdf related to that url on the site. Or should I approach this differently? I've tried searching but couldn't find anything that worked, I'm pretty new to S3 so I'm a little lost.

The best solution I could come up with ATM is using dynamic routes in NextJS (13.4 app router) to get the path based on the object name in s3 and then embed the pdf on the site, the dynamic routes I'm fine with but in terms of fetching the PDF from S3 I'm stuck.

I've tried using an API call and send GET requests to a pre-signed URL, however that doesn't really work as from what I know the presigned URL expires after a limited amount of time and if I'd rather not make the bucket public. (once again, I'm fairly new to S3 and the docs don't help much so I may be entirely wrong.)

Thanks

Comment: One of the tricks you could use here is, serving your files which needs to be downloaded as a static website. Then, you can point your domain's DNS to your s3 bucket, where end user will see the download was initiated from your domain. Here's a good tutorial to do what I just mentioned: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/cjn-how-to-point-your-domain-to-s3-website-bucket/

Answer (score 0):

You can lock your bucket down so that it is only publicly accessible via `GET` requests. This might be useful in your case. Make your bucket public and then add a Bucket Policy such as:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1679789966659",
  "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "Stmt167978995632",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

Bear in mind that all objects in `your-bucket-name` will be public using this approach. This can be helpful if you want users to bookmark the page (pdf) but not if you want to control access to these pdfs. Such as a user having to login to your application and be authorised to view different ones.

If you want to keep your S3 bucket from being publicly accessible and you are indeed controlling access to the pdfs based on user accounts then the best option is to use pre-signed urls.

Since you're using Node you can route your `GET` requests to a middleware function that checks to see if your user is allowed to view the PDF. For example, if your user browses to:

```
domain.com/exams/{biology}/{photosynthesis 1.pdf}
```

then in your router pass their userid and check against the database to see if they are authorised to view it. If they are then use the AWS SDK for JavaScript to create a pre-signed url and return the `GET` request response to the pre-signed url. See [aws docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generate-presigned-url-modular-aws-sdk-javascript/) on how to "Generate a presigned URL for GetObject".

The s3 client library is very good and you can set the duration of validity or the pre-signed urls using the `expiresIn` property. For example 1 minute would be:

```
const url = await getSignedUrl(client, command, { expiresIn: 60 });
```